# Convert Excel Sheet to PDFs, Infinite Loop Error

Tags: excel, vba, pdf-generation, infinite-loop

I have used bits and pieces of code on forums to create a macro that exports PDF's from a single sheet in excel. Each PDF contains the header and all relevant rows to the employee (all rows with employee ID). When I run it all goes well and the pdfs are correct, however the macro never stops running.

**I believe I have created an infinite loop and am not sure how to correct it.**

It also creates a PDF just containing the header that is not necessary.

```
Sub PracticeToPDF()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim ws_unique As Worksheet
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim iLastRow As Long
Dim iLastRow_unique As Long
Dim UniqueRng As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Note that the macro will save the pdf files in this active directory so you should save in an appropriate folder
DirectoryLocation = ActiveWorkbook.Path

Set ws = Worksheets("BootVSPayroll") 'Amend to reflect the sheet you wish to work with
Set ws_unique = Worksheets("BootVSPayroll") 'Amend to reflect the sheet you wish to work with

'Find the last row in each worksheet
iLastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
iLastRow_unique = ws_unique.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row


With ws
    'I've set my range to reflect my headers which are fixed for this report
    Set DataRange = ws.Range("$A$1:$K$1" & iLastRow)

    'autofilter field is 4 as I want to print based on the practice value in column D
    DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1

    Set UniqueRng = ws_unique.Range("A1:A20" & iLastRow_unique)
    For Each Cell In UniqueRng
        DataRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Cell

    Name = DirectoryLocation & "\" & Cell.Value & " BOOT Report" & ".pdf"

    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=Name _
    , Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
    :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

    Next Cell

End With
With ws
     .Protect Userinterfaceonly:=True, _
     DrawingObjects:=False, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
    True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True
     .EnableOutlining = True
     .EnableAutoFilter = True
     If .FilterMode Then
        .ShowAllData
     End If
 End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you perhaps mean for:

```
Set DataRange = ws.Range("$A$1:$K$1" & iLastRow)
...
Set UniqueRng = ws_unique.Range("A1:A20" & iLastRow_unique)
```

to instead be:

```
Set DataRange = ws.Range("$A$1:$K$" & iLastRow)
...
Set UniqueRng = ws_unique.Range("A1:A" & iLastRow_unique)
```

?

If, for example, (taken from ws_unique) your last used row, `iLastRow_unique` equals 200, then `"A1:A20" & iLastRow_unique` is equivalent to `"A1:A20200"` -- which may be a lot more rows that you intended to loop through, I think.

Comment: Your a wizard, thanks George. The only thing I need to fix now is it creates an extra pdf just containing the headers that is not necessary.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the worksheet looks like so I'm just spitballing here, but I'll give it a stab.  Is the "extra" PDF the first one it generates?  If so you may want one or both of those ranges to start one row or column over.  My guess would be that UniqueRng might need to start at A2 rather than A1, but again that's kind of a blind guess without seeing the worksheet.

If instead it's the last PDF generated, it could be that there is a space or some other unintended content in the row right after the last "real" one, and it's creating a PDF out of that.